# Why does my CSS variable remain unused when trying to use it in an animation?

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate a falling object, with translateX being random. Everything about the code works, apart from my variable transX.

The part of changing the value via JavaScript works perfectly fine, however the value just isn't used.

Why will it not work?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var e = document.createElement("li");
  e.style.setProperty("--transX", (Math.random() * 50 - 25).toFixed(0) + "px");
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(e);
}, 100);
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1eb500;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  animation-name: fall;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.66, -0.06, .77, .12);
  opacity: 0%;
  list-style-type: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  --transX: 100px;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(2000px) translateX(var(--transX)) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: share a full working example

Comment: @Temani Afif How do I do that? I'm new, sorry.

Comment: sahre the HTML and the JS you are using like you did with the CSS

Comment: @Ewasted edit your question use tool `<>` and paste minium code like css js and html.

Comment: Try to define your variable in a `:root` block like described in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where are you applying the animation? Variables in CSS should be declared within a CSS selector that defines its scope. For a global scope you can use either the :root or the body selector

```
:root {
 --transX: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @Ewasted are you sure this worked? it doesn't make sense to declare the variable inside root if you want each element to have a different value.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Although I should've mentioned, that the JavaScript code is executed in an Interval. I created the element, then changed the value of the variable and then appended it to a <ul> tag. I apologize for the missing stuff, I'm quite in a hurry.

Comment: @Ewasted still doesn't make sense and the code you shared already work fine

Comment: The thing I intended only worked with @Moneer Kamal 's answer. Without :root the animation itself worked, although translateX did not.